# How to add the search and clear icons in the bootstrap search box

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my project i need to include the search and clear icons in the bootstrap search box like in the below image

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do this.

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control">
  <span class="input-group-addon glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
</div>
```

See the output [here](http://bootply.com/109217)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do it but one simple way is to create three elements within one relatively positioned parent. You'll need to fudge this a bit but it should get you going.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search YouTube" class="form-control">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrap{
    position: relative;
}
.wrap span{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 3px;
}
.wrap .glyphicon-remove-circle {
    left: auto;
    right: 3px;
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: I believe Bootstrap already provide preset styles so that you don't need to mess with the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

If you add the jQuery Mobile js file to your page, you can simply add

```
type="search"
```

and

```
data-clear-btn="true"
```

to the element and they will appear automatically.